# Why would NIntegrate give a negative value for this strictly-positive integrand?

Tags: numerical-integration

[image]

```
NIntegrate[
 Exp[Log[(a/3 - c/3) (a/3 - b/2 + c/6) (a/3 + b/2 + c/6)] + 
    1/2 (-((15 a^2)/4) - (15 b^2)/4 - (5 c^2)/4)] Boole[
   c >= b >= 0] Boole[c >= a], {a, -Infinity, Infinity}, {b, 0, 
  Infinity}, {c, 0, Infinity}]
```

The integrand is an exponential (plus some Boole terms which should not affect the sign of the integrand), i.e. it is strictly positive, so why is the result negative?

What I've found while poking around: the result flips to positive if I delete the first term in the logarithm, $(\frac{a}{3}-\frac{c}{3})$. The restriction imposed by the second Boole term, $c\geq a$, forces this term to be strictly negative, which could cause a problem since the logarithm of a negative number is complex and the integration is only over real numbers. However that still shouldn't be fatal, since there are three terms multiplied together in the logarithm, and although this term is negative, the others could easily be negative as well to yield a positive value.

It's not like these values don't exist: for example $a=1,b=2,c=3$ satisfies both Boole conditions, is within the integration range, and yields a positive value for the logarithm:

[image]

```
(a/3 - c/3) (a/3 - b/2 + c/6) (a/3 + b/2 + c/6) /. {a -> 1, b -> 2, 
  c -> 3}
```

Because this point exists, it seems the numerical integral should as well (and should be positive).

What's up?

Comment: For a real number `x`, `Exp[x]` is always positive. For complex numbers `Exp[x]` can be negative. For a positive number `y`, `Log[y]` is always real (at least the principal branch is), but for negative `y` it will be complex. For your integration range, the argument of `Log` can be negative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't tell what Boole is doing inside the integral there, but if you break the 3 integrals one by one, you can see that the integrand is not all positive actually.

```
ClearAll[a,b,c]
tmp = Exp[Log[(a/3 - c/3) (a/3 - b/2 + c/6) (a/3 + b/2 + c/6)]
    + 1/2 (-((15 a^2)/4) - (15 b^2)/4 - (5 c^2)/4)];
r0 = Integrate[tmp*Boole[c >= b >= 0]*Boole[c >= a], {a, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
 r1 = Integrate[r0, {b, 0, Infinity}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Before integrating the above over `c`, plotting it shows it is not all positive

```
 Plot[r1, {c, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

That is why `NIntegrate[r1, {c, 0, Infinity}]` gives `-0.000820548` which is the same result obtained when doing the whole integration all at once

```
NIntegrate[
 tmp*Boole[c >= b >= 0]*Boole[c >= a], {a, -Infinity, Infinity}, {b, 
  0, Infinity}, {c, 0, Infinity}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So the integrand does not appear to be all positive as you say, at least according to Mathematica. Ofcourse, Mathematica Integrate result could be wrong above. But assuming it is correct, the above shows why you get negative result.

ps. Tried `Integrate[r1, {c, 0, Infinity}]` But it could not do it after waiting some time.

Comment: Hmm, how is that possible though? The integrand's still an exponential, how can it become negative ... ?

Comment: @Allure:The integrand takes negative values too, e. g. Exp[Log[(a/3 - c/3) (a/3 - b/2 + c/6) (a/3 + b/2 + c/6)] + 
   1/2 (-((15 a^2)/4) - (15 b^2)/4 - (5 c^2)/4) /. {a -> 11, b -> 9, 
   c -> 10001/10}] performs $$-\frac{38243713053}{4000 e^{100080601/160}} .$$